# Как сделать ответ целого числа а не десятичной дроби?

Tags: python, математика

Я делаю математический тест в котором есть функция деления. Делители выдают случайные числа и ответ получается дробью. Как сделать так, чтоб когда пользователь писал ответ, ему было бы достаточно написать целое число и не писать саму десятичную дробь?

Answer (score 4):

Давайте ему только такие значения, чтобы ответ был целым.

В задании `m = n/k` не "загадывайте" случайные `n` и `k`, а загадывайте `m` и `k`, вычисляйте `n` и задавайте свой вопрос. Тогда ответ всегда будет точным целым.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше убрать дроби в ответе.
Для этого можете воспользоваться
math.ceil(X) – округление до ближайшего большего числа.
math.floor(X) - округление вниз.